# ¿Por qué Glide no carga mi imagen?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide, glide

Estoy tratando de usar Glide para no quedarme sin memoria al usar imágenes pero no logro hacer que funcione. Cual es el problema?

https://github.com/agusval1994/Glide2

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.asteroide)
            .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.agusv.glide2"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.1'

      implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
   }
```

Resultado: No muestra nada no entiendo porque

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que tipo de imagen es asteroide, png, jpg o vector asset (.xml) ? @Zekirak Revisa la imagen, ¿no es una transparencia .png?

Comment: Hola, ahí edite la pregunta mostrando la imagen que quiero usar, es PNG

Comment: ¿muestra algún error?, o únicamente entra la aplicación pero no se muestra la imagen. @Zekirak

Comment: Tu código es correcto debería funcionar, solo usas una Activity?

Comment: Si es la unica activity que tengo

Comment: Yo uso  compileSdkVersion 26  eso no es el problema @Zekirak por cierto  veo que usas un emulador, has probado en un dispositivo físico ?

Comment: @Zekirak no debe existir ningún problema usando emulador o celular, podrías subir tu proyecto en algún lugar, e. github?

Comment: Hola, ya lo puse en github, puse el link en la pregunta

Comment: has probado con alguna otra forma? en mi caso si me funciona como lo tienes, excepto que la imagen la tengo en drawable, no en drawable-v24

Comment: @Zekirak revisa mi solucion si te es util.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se da porque al parecer definiste una carpeta `drawable` con compatibilidad solo para version android API 24 (`drawable-v24`) en la carpeta res del proyecto. Al parecer [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) tiene problemas para identificar el recurso `asteroide.png`.

Para reproducir el error basta con ejecutar la aplicacion en dispositivos `Android != Api 24`.

**La solucion:** mueve la imagen a la carpeta `drawable` por default. Asi te aseguras que cualquier version de android tome la ruta de la imagen y sea mostrada.

> Si la version de Android es la especificada para la carpeta, ira
>   directamente a acceder al recurso. De lo contrario ira a buscarla a la
>   carpeta drawable, como [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) utiliza rutas especificas, lanza una
>   excepcion interna de que el recurso no existe y por eso no se
>   visualiza la imagen.

Comment: Si, era eso. Nunca me hubiera dado cuenta. Muchas gracias